# How to remove alpha of iconView in GoogleMaps?

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I know it sounds easy but by default GoogleMaps default function iconView has a default alpha of 0.9. I tried changing it to 1 but it's still the same. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]
This is my code

```
        let cView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,400*PT,300*PT))
        let innerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,400*PT,190*PT))
        innerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        innerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        innerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        innerView.alpha = 1
        cView.addSubview(innerView)
        let cIcon = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0*PT, 200*PT, 90*PT, 100*PT))
        cIcon.image = UIImage(named: "1.png")
        cView.addSubview(cIcon)
        cView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        item.iconView = cView
```

[EDIT]
Added screenshot of the output

[image]

[EDIT]
Final output after the answer below

[image]

Comment: [Opacity is set on the GMSMarker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#ab3a0c24528927eeba06b01e23070e823), not the marker's `iconView`, and it defaults to `1`. `iconView` is also not a function.

Comment: I understand, but if you try and use iconView you can see that the background is barely visible like it's alpha is 0.9. So I tried to set my customView that I added to iconView to alpha = 1, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a bit obvious, but can you try adding this?

```
item.opacity = 1
```